# Gitlab redirects to other page

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab

I had my gitlab installation for some time now. The other day few days ago I did a update using [this tutorial](https://about.gitlab.com/upgrade-to-package-repository/). I'd played a little with the settings in admin panel, and right now everytime I try to access my gitlab panel I got redirected to some other page (our organization homepage, diffrent domain, diffrent everything).

I don't even see a login page, just got 302 http response.

Is there any configuration option that might cause this? How can I find and fix it?

I got it installed on basic windows azure linux instance with no changes in the configuration. Also, I do not get 302 when gitlab is satarting (f.e. after system reeboot) - then I got 503 with info that the request took too long - therefore I assume it's not the system or webserver - just gitlab does the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably set a page to redirect non-logged in users to.

[image]

Try accessing `your-domain.example.com/users/sign_in` and log in with an administrator account to change this setting.

Comment: That was it, I found the answer before but forgot to put it here. Thank you.